# Windows PowerShell, PadLeft

Tags: windows, powershell, file, padleft

i need to make files name string like *text*_000.txt, where 000 should increase every file but i got problem like this where after 10 iterations the digits in the file name become more than necessary

i need to get file name like "text_001.mp3"
and it's ok for 9 files, but after i got "text_0010"

this is code

```
*param (
[string]$dir = "C:\Users\Администратор\Desktop\music"
)
Set-Location -Path $dir
$count=1
Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime | % { Rename-Item $_ -NewName (‘text' + '{0}'.PadLeft(5,"0") -f $count++ + '.txt') }*
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably easier to directly format your filename [number with leading zeros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros), like:

```
'text_{0:000}.txt' -f [int]$Count
```

e.g.:

```
'text_{0:000}.txt' -f 17
text_017.txt
```

Also knowing that this will properly overflow (prevent duplicate filenames):

```
'text_{0:000}.txt' -f 1234
text_1234.txt
```

In your case:

```
... | Foreach-Object { Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('text_{0:000}.txt' -f $count++) }
```

Comment: yea this is helped me ty!!!